# QDateTime fromString formate have bug

Tags: qt

The Qt version which I use is 5.4. When I try this code blow, the result is OK

```
QString dateString = "Mar 4, 2015";
QDateTime dateData = QDateTime::fromString(dateString, "MMM dd, yyyy");
qDebug() << "data:" << dateData.toString("yyyy dd MM");
```

the result is data: `2015 04 03`.
But when I change the string to `Mar 3, 2015`, the result is "". Why?

```
QString dateString = "Mar 3, 2015";
QDateTime dateData = QDateTime::fromString(dateString, "MMM dd, yyyy");
qDebug() << "data:" << dateData.toString("yyyy dd MM");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like undefined behaviour because you specified "dd" which assumes a leading zero.

this works fine:

```
QString dateString = "Mar 3, 2015";
QDateTime dateData = QDateTime::fromString(dateString, "MMM d, yyyy");
qDebug() << "data:" << dateData.toString("yyyy dd MM");
```

Comment: You are right. But I do not have enough reputation to let your answer useful. sorry.

Comment: you're welcome. pretty sure the 'accept answer' is available to you as well, and accepting answers bumps your reputation ;)  @GuangliHu